# How to perform text classification with naive bayes using sklearn library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying text classification using naive bayes text classifier.
My data is in the below format and based on the question and excerpt i have to decide the topic of the question. The training data is having more than 20K records. I know SVM would be a better option here but i want to go with [Naive Bayes using sklearn library](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html).

```
{[{"topic":"electronics","question":"What is the effective differencial effective of this circuit","excerpt":"I'm trying to work out, in general terms, the effective capacitance of this circuit (see diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS85b.png).  \n\nWhat is the effective capacitance of this circuit and will the ...\r\n        "},
{"topic":"electronics","question":"Outlet Installation--more wires than my new outlet can use [on hold]","excerpt":"I am replacing a wall outlet with a Cooper Wiring USB outlet (TR7745).  The new outlet has 3 wires coming out of it--a black, a white, and a green.  Each one needs to be attached with a wire nut to ...\r\n        "}]}
```

This is what i have tried so far,

```
import numpy as np
import json
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *

topic = []
question = []
excerpt = []

with open('training.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        topic.append(data["topic"])
        question.append(data["question"])
        excerpt.append(data["excerpt"])

unique_topics = list(set(topic))
new_topic = [x.encode('UTF8') for x in topic]
numeric_topics = [name.replace('gis', '1').replace('security', '2').replace('photo', '3').replace('mathematica', '4').replace('unix', '5').replace('wordpress', '6').replace('scifi', '7').replace('electronics', '8').replace('android', '9').replace('apple', '10') for name in new_topic]
numeric_topics = [float(i) for i in numeric_topics]

x1 = np.array(question)
x2 = np.array(excerpt)
X = zip(*[x1,x2])
Y = np.array(numeric_topics)
print X[0]
clf = BernoulliNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
print "Prediction:", clf.predict( ['hello'] )
```

But as expected i am getting ValueError: could not convert string to float. My question is how can i create a simple classifier to classify the question and excerpt into related topic ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All classifiers in sklearn require input to be represented as vectors of some fixed dimensionality. For text there are [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), [`HashingVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) and [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) which can transform your strings into vectors of floating numbers.

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(X)
```

Obviously, you'll need to vectorize your test set in the same way

```
clf.predict( vect.transform(['hello']) )
```

See a [tutorial on using sklearn with textual data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html).

Comment: I am getting error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower' while using X = vect.fit_transform(X), X is a iterable list..